How to implement OAuth 2.0 certificate authentication in Node JS
I'm working on a Node.js application that uses Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) to authenticate with Microsoft Graph API using OAuth 2.0.
Currently, authentication is handled using a client secret, but the goal is to improve security by switching to a client certificate instead.
Here’s the current implementation for acquiring an access token with the clientSecret:
const config = {
    auth: {
        clientId: clientId,
        authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}`,
        clientSecret: clientSecret,
    }
};

const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(config);

const request = {
    scopes: ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'],
};

async function getAccessToken() {
    try {
        const response = await cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential(request);
        return response.accessToken;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error acquiring token: ${error}`);
    }
}

Additionally, this function is used to fetch a list of users from Microsoft Graph API:
async function listUsers() {
    const token = await getAccessToken();
    if (!token) {
        console.error('Failed to acquire access token');
        return;
    }

    const options = {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
        }
    };

    try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users', options);
        console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error fetching users: ${error}`);
    }
}

The goal now is to replace the clientSecret with a client certificate to enhance security. What changes are needed to modify the MSAL configuration for using client certificate instead?

Could you include how you generated the certificate and have you added it in application?

In my case, I used below commands to create private key and certificate:
openssl genrsa -out private.key 2048
openssl req -new -key private.key -out request.csr
openssl x509 -req -in request.csr -signkey private.key -out certificate.crt -days 365
Get-Content private.key, certificate.crt | Set-Content certificate.pem

Now, make sure to upload certificate.crt file in your Entra ID app registration like this:

When I ran below modified code, I got the list of users successfully in my Node JS application:
const msal = require('@azure/msal-node');
const fs = require('fs');

const clientId = 'appId';
const tenantId = 'tenantId';

const certificatePath = './certificate.pem';
const certificate = fs.readFileSync(certificatePath, 'utf8');

const config = {
    auth: {
        clientId: clientId,
        authority: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}`,
        clientCertificate: {
            thumbprint: '5AA5151C05CC022xxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
            privateKey: certificate,
        },
    },
};

const cca = new msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(config);

const request = {
    scopes: ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default'],
};

async function getAccessToken() {
    try {
        const response = await cca.acquireTokenByClientCredential(request);
        return response.accessToken;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error acquiring token: ${error}`);
    }
}

async function listUsers() {
    const token = await getAccessToken();
    if (!token) {
        console.error('Failed to acquire access token');
        return;
    }

    const axios = require('axios');
    const options = {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
    };

    try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users', options);
        console.log(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error fetching users: ${error}`);
    }
}

listUsers();

Response:

